# Inserting Application User Name

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to store the application user-name (**NOT** the **SYSTEM_USER**) along with each and every record I insert from front-end application(C#). 
Can anyone suggest a nice method to bind the application user-name as default column value instead of passing it as a parameter to the SP?

Comment: Your application can set the user name into the `CONTEXT_INFO` before every query and you could have a default expression that reads it from that. What type of application is it and what data access layer are you using?

Comment: @MartinSmith +1, nice one

Comment: Its our in-house C# application and I was planning to attach the user name along with the connection string.

Comment: @Appyks - If the application is single user you could send this along with the `APP_NAME()` which would be easier as it wouldn't require a separate `SET CONTEXT_INFO` call. If it is multi user I think this will have implications for connection pooling.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thanks Martin,great this would help me a lot

Comment: SQL is not my strong point, but I'm curios about it: what if the `Username` column accepts NULL values and is indexed, would it be a huge hit on the SQL server to alter the table by setting the default constraint value on the column, inserting the rows and then dropping the default constraint?

Comment: Also you can make a table (SPID,YourUserName) and use a process id -[@@SPID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189535.aspx) to insert/update this table with a user name on your app start and use `select YourUserName from t where SPID=@@SPID` to get a user name in a SP to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a reference to a function that returns the user of interest in your class constructor, and call that inside the method that execs the proc - eg:

```
public class SomeContext
{
  private readonly Func<string> getUserName;
  public SomeContext(Func<string> getUserName)
  (
    this.getUserName = getUserName;
  )

  public void SaveSomething(\* parameters here *\)
  {
    // build your proc based on someThing plus 'this.getUserName();'
    var cmd = "Exec whatever";
    ExecuteSqlCommand(cmd);
  }
}
```

You could wire up `SomeContext` using a dependancy injection framework and bind the `getUserName` parameter to a function that returns the user name you're interested in (`() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` in ASP.Net MVC, for example).

Then at run-time, when you call `SaveSomething`, the user name will be sent up to SQL as an argument to the proc.

Comment: If the question is so vague as to make it "hard to make any meaningful suggestions" (your words), perhaps it would be better not to offer a **specific** suggestion based on a framework that isn't indicated as being applicable? (Well, your question is a generic one about <some subject>, so here's an answer based on <some framework or API that's specific and may not be applicable at all to your needs or situation>.)

Comment: Fair enough, I used EF/MVC as part of my example but that was getting in the way of the meat of the answer - injecting `Func<string>` to get the username at run time. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Can’t understand what’s unclear in it!!! Have a look at the comment (suggestion) by Mr MartinSmith and I am happy with the solution what he had given..